# How to add a filter to “QFileDialog.getOpenFileName”

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt4

I would like to add a filter to the following code in order to select only the “CSV files”, but I did not succeed:

```
def filePath(title):
    qfd = QFileDialog()
    path = "D:\ennine\SIG HTB\BGN"
    f = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(qfd, title, path)
    return f
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the documentation you can add filter in the definition of your class:

> QString QFileDialog.getOpenFileName (QWidget parent = None, QString caption = QString(), QString directory = QString(), QString filter = QString(), Options options = 0)

So with your code it should looks like :

```
def filePath(title):
    qfd = QFileDialog()
    path = "D:\ennine\SIG HTB\BGN"
    filter = "csv(*.csv)"
    f = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(qfd, title, path, filter)
    return f
```

You can also add other filter. You need to separate them with a double **;;** like so :

> "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg);;Text files (*.txt);;XML files (*.xml)"

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. However, I received the following error: f = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(qfd, title, path, filter)
TypeError: QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(QWidget parent=None, QString caption=QString(), QString directory=QString(), QString filter=QString(), QString selectedFilter=None, QFileDialog.Options options=0): argument 4 has unexpected type 'builtin_function_or_method'

Comment: Many thanks. A small error of typing (The fourth line of the code should be : filter instead of filer)

Comment: Yeah my bad I didn't red carrefully. Glad it helps you help and thank you for upvoting. ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()

fname = dialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Window name", "", "CSV files (*.csv)")
```

Will do the job.

Just pass None as 1st agrument.